# Subtracting values in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I have prices in two different tables and want to subtract them (current price-last day price) and ORDER them in DESC form. I was wondering if it can be done using a single MySQL command.

Table Structure

```
Table 1
id | Item Name | Date       | Price
 1 | alpha     | 2011-10-05 | 10
 2 | beta      | 2011-10-05 | 12
 3 | gamma     | 2011-10-05 | 14 

Table 2
id | Item Name | Date       | Price
 1 | alpha     | 2011-10-04 | 8
 2 | beta      | 2011-10-04 | 10
 3 | gamma     | 2011-10-04 | 12
 4 | alpha     | 2011-10-03 | 4
 5 | beta      | 2011-10-03 | 6
 6 | gamma     | 2011-10-03 | 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
table1.id, table1.`Item Name`,
table1.`Date` AS CurrDate, table1.Price AS CurrPrice,
table2.`Date` AS PrevDate, table2.Price AS PrevPrice,
table1.Price - table2.Price AS Difference
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id AND table1.`Date` - INTERVAL 1 DAY = table2.`Date`
ORDER BY Difference DESC
```

There is nothing special about this query except the way I've used the LEFT JOIN. I believe if yesterday's rates for a record are not available, the the last three columns would contain NULL. Output:

```
id | Item Name | CurrDate   | CurrPrice | PrevDate   | PrevPrice | Difference
2  | beta      | 2011-10-05 | 12        | 2011-10-04 | 10        | 2
3  | gamma     | 2011-10-05 | 14        | 2011-10-04 | 12        | 2
1  | alpha     | 2011-10-05 | 10        | 2011-10-04 | 8         | 2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
  a.price as price1
  , IFNULL(b.price,'(no data)') as price2
  , (a.price - IFNULL(b.price,0)) as difference
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.`item name` = b.`item name`)
GROUP BY a.`item name`
HAVING IFNULL(b.`date`,'') = MAX(IFNULL(b.`date`,'')
```

Here's how it works.

It selects data from 2 tables: All data from table1 and matching data from table2.
If it cannot find matching data from table2 it will substitute `null` values in place of the missing rows. *(`left join`)*

Then it groups *(`group by`)* rows together based on `table1.item name`.
This combines multiple rows per item.
The `having` clause fixes this by only selecting the newest date rows from table2.

*A small correction is build into the `select` and `having` clauses to deal with the case when there is no data in table2 to match table1.*

Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
  s.closing as price1
  , IFNULL(sh.closing,'(no data)') as price2
  , (s.closing - IFNULL(sh.closing,0)) as difference 
FROM stocks s 
LEFT JOIN stockhistory sh ON (s.symbol = sh.symbol) 
GROUP BY s.symbol 
HAVING IFNULL(sh.edate,'') = MAX(IFNULL(sh.edate,'')
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I would really appreciate if you could explain it a little too so that it is helpful in the future :)

Comment: I am getting the following error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: @SaadBashir, My query does not have `limit`, please copy-paste the whole query in a comment and I'll have a look. (BTW `limit 30 offset 0` is the **last** statement in the query, not part of the select clause)

Comment: This is the exact code i ran in the phpmyadmin SQL console area and got the above mentioned error: SELECT a.closing as price1, IFNULL(b.closing,'(no data)') as price2, (a.closing - IFNULL(b.closing,0)) as difference FROM stocks a LEFT JOIN stockhistory b ON (a.`symbol` = b.`symbol`) GROUP BY a.`symbol` HAVING IFNULL(b.`edate`,'') = MAX(IFNULL(b.`edate`,'')

Comment: @SaadBashir, there is no `limit` clause in that line! So it's clearly impossible for MySQL to complain 'bout syntax errors near `limit`.