# query the first sql column to subtract the other column

Tags: php, sql, subtraction

I have this table in my sql and I want to use `cus_count1` value to subtract `cus_count2` value. I want to query it, but I am not sure how do I go about doing it.

```
+---------------------+------------+------------+
|        Time         | cus_count1 | cus_count2 |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-12-21 08:28:44 |          1 |          0 |
| 2015-12-21 08:29:09 |          2 |          1 |
| 2015-12-21 08:29:23 |          3 |          1 |
| 2015-12-21 08:29:35 |          4 |          1 |
| 2015-12-21 08:29:49 |          4 |          2 |
| 2015-12-21 08:30:09 |          5 |          2 |
| 2015-12-21 08:30:17 |          6 |          2 |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query1 = "SELECT time,  cus_count1 - cus_count2 AS cus_flow FROM new_tbl_cus";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
     {


        $dataset1[] = array(strtotime($row['time'])*1000,$row['cus_flow']);
        //echo strtotime($row['time'])*1000;

    }
?>
```

Comment: You use  a minus just like in school math. Did you not Google something like "how to substract mysql"?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660808/subtracting-values-in-mysql-table

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want simple subtraction? If yes, you could just do:

```
select time, cus_count1 - cus_count2 as finalvalue
from tablename
```

I guess you might be asking for something different, or is it really this what you are asking for? In the above statement, finalvalue is the artificial column name (aka alias) given to the calculated/derived column.

Comment: hi, updated is my php code, but my subtraction got 4 as the final value, when it should be 3. do help! :-(

Comment: Shoudn't each row get a different answer? For example, 2015-12-21 08:28:44's cus_count1- cus_count2 will be 1-0 = 1. For 2015-12-21 08:29:09, the subtraction will be 1 as well...and so on. Subtraction will result in 4 for 2015-12-21 08:30:17 (6-2 = 4). Is that what you want, or do you want something else?

Comment: If either of the answers helped you, please mark them as accepted to put closure to your question. If you found a solution different from the answers, feel free to add your answer and then mark it as accepted so that others can find this question and supporting answer. Thank you @p0ny.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 SELECT *,  cus_count1 - cus_count2 as diff FROM [dbo].tablename
```

as the SQL.

you will get an extra column Diff as the last column in the resultset.

If you were to subtract for a specific row please add a **WHERE** clause on the primary key for the table or a subsequent table column